# polygonally connected set and directional derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be polygonally connected if for every $\vec{a},\vec{b} \in A$, we can find some points $\vec{x}_0,\ldots,\vec{x}_k \in A$ such that $\vec{x}_0 =\vec{a}, \vec{x}_k=\vec{b}$, and such that $Co(\vec{x}_{j-1},\vec{x}_j) \subseteq A$ for every $1 \leq j \leq k$ where $Co(\vec{x},\vec{y}):=\{(1-t)\vec{x}+t\vec{y} \mid 0\leq t \leq 1 \}$

Problem: Let A be a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is polygonally connected. Let $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a function which has the following property: $$(\partial_{\vec{v}}f)(\vec{a}) \text{exists and is equal to 0 for every $\vec{a} \in A$ and every $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$}$$. **Prove that f is a constant function.**

the definition of polygonally connected gives too much information that i dont know how to use. i know in one variable calculus if the derivative is equal to 0 for all elements in the domain, then we can know it must be a constant function. however, this time it became a multi-variable case, i just dont know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Take $a,b \in R^n$  now take a polygon path connecting $a$ to $b$, call it by $P$ according to assumption $f$ is constant on any segment, since our polygon $P$ is finite union of segments so $f$ is constant on whole $P$ therefore $f(a)=f(b)$